# App submission fails with 1016 related to Microsoft.Advertising.Mobile.resources.dll

Tags: windows-phone-8

I'm trying to submit my app to the Windows Phone 8 store, and it fails with the following errors:

```
1016: A file registered in the app manifest is missing: pl-PL/Microsoft.Advertising.Mobile.resources.dll. Use a different one and then try again 
1016: A file registered in the app manifest is missing: it-IT/Microsoft.Advertising.Mobile.resources.dll. Use a different one and then try again 
1016: A file registered in the app manifest is missing: ko-KR/Microsoft.Advertising.Mobile.resources.dll. Use a different one and then try again 
1016: A file registered in the app manifest is missing: fr-FR/Microsoft.Advertising.Mobile.resources.dll. Use a different one and then try again 
1016: A file registered in the app manifest is missing: zh-TW/Microsoft.Advertising.Mobile.resources.dll. Use a different one and then try again 
1016: A file registered in the app manifest is missing: ja-JP/Microsoft.Advertising.Mobile.resources.dll. Use a different one and then try again 
1016: A file registered in the app manifest is missing: es-ES/Microsoft.Advertising.Mobile.resources.dll. Use a different one and then try again 
1016: A file registered in the app manifest is missing: pt-PT/Microsoft.Advertising.Mobile.resources.dll. Use a different one and then try again 
1016: A file registered in the app manifest is missing: el-GR/Microsoft.Advertising.Mobile.resources.dll. Use a different one and then try again
```

If I crack open the xap and manually delete the following lines from my AppManifest.xaml:

```
<AssemblyPart Source="cs-CZ/Microsoft.Advertising.Mobile.resources.dll" />
<AssemblyPart Source="de-DE/Microsoft.Advertising.Mobile.resources.dll" />
<AssemblyPart Source="el-GR/Microsoft.Advertising.Mobile.resources.dll" />
<AssemblyPart Source="es-ES/Microsoft.Advertising.Mobile.resources.dll" />
<AssemblyPart Source="fr-FR/Microsoft.Advertising.Mobile.resources.dll" />
<AssemblyPart Source="it-IT/Microsoft.Advertising.Mobile.resources.dll" />
<AssemblyPart Source="ja-JP/Microsoft.Advertising.Mobile.resources.dll" />
<AssemblyPart Source="ko-KR/Microsoft.Advertising.Mobile.resources.dll" />
<AssemblyPart Source="pl-PL/Microsoft.Advertising.Mobile.resources.dll" />
<AssemblyPart Source="pt-PT/Microsoft.Advertising.Mobile.resources.dll" />
<AssemblyPart Source="ru-RU/Microsoft.Advertising.Mobile.resources.dll" />
<AssemblyPart Source="zh-CN/Microsoft.Advertising.Mobile.resources.dll" />
<AssemblyPart Source="zh-TW/Microsoft.Advertising.Mobile.resources.dll" />
```

after submission I get:

```
We weren't able to save your info. Try again. Error code: 0x80040803
```

Anyone else had this problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar error message. I adopted another approach: instead of editing the manifest file I added the missing DLL in the XAP archive.

Alex.

Answer (score 2):

You need to make sure you have the latest version of the ad sdk. I think it's v7.1 not v6.1.

I had similar warnings when I tried to upload my xap a couple of hours ago.

- 1016: A file registered in the app manifest is missing:
  zh-Hant/Microsoft.Expression.Interactions.resources.dll. Use a
  different one and then try again
- 1016: A file registered in the app manifest is missing:
  zh-Hans/System.Windows.Interactivity.resources.dll. Use a different
  one and then try again

Turned out there's new version for Microsoft.Expression.Interactions and System.Windows.Interactivity in wp8. After changing the reference to the latest version, no error was thrown during the submission.

Btw rather than waiting for the xap file to upload, a quicker way to test this is to launch Store Test Kit --> Automated Tests.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Doing a full search for Microsoft.Expression.Interactions.dll on my system, I found the following:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Expression\Blend\Windows Phone\v7.0\Libraries\Microsoft.Expression.Interactions.dll
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Expression\Blend\Windows Phone\v7.1\Libraries\Microsoft.Expression.Interactions.dll
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Expression\Blend\Windows Phone\v8.0\Libraries\Microsoft.Expression.Interactions.dll

I am already pointing the reference at the v8.0 dll so it is using the latest.