# Windows Phone 8: Some files are not added to XAP file on build

Tags: telerik, windows-phone-8

I'm building a Windows Phone 8 app in which I'm using the Telerik Rad Controls for WP8. The app is localised to en-US, en-GB, da-DK, de-DE, fr-FR, es-ES & it-IT. When I run the Store Test Kit I get the following error;

```
[ERROR]: A file registered in the AppManifest.xaml is missing: fr-FR/Telerik.Windows.Controls.Input.resources.dll.
[ERROR]: A file registered in the AppManifest.xaml is missing: it-IT/Telerik.Windows.Controls.Input.resources.dll.
[ERROR]: A file registered in the AppManifest.xaml is missing: it-IT/Telerik.Windows.Controls.Primitives.resources.dll.
```

The file are present in the relative /Bin/Release folders but are not being included in the .xap file. I've cracked open the xap and the correct files are added for all other languages but the above 3 are definitely missing.

I'm using the latest build of RadControls (2012.3.1211 DEC. 11, 2012)

Does anyone have any idea what the problem may be?

Cheers
Si

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears others are having similar problems but no solutions: [App submission fails with 1016 related to Microsoft.Advertising.Mobile.resources.dll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13449614/app-submission-fails-with-1016-related-to-microsoft-advertising-mobile-resources)

As a work around the files can be added post-build and the xap then passes the Store Test Kit (and I assume will pass certification!).

I have 7zip installed so to fix my specific issue I used the following Post-build event command lines:

```
"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a -tzip $(TargetDir)<YOUR XAP FILE NAME>.xap $(TargetDir)it-IT\
"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a -tzip $(TargetDir)<YOUR XAP FILE NAME>.xap $(TargetDir)fr-FR\
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to set the Build Action of your resources.dll to Content, Compile or Embedded Ressource? This way the files should be included during the build process.